# "Could not resolve all dependencies" with 3rd party libs (from Maven Central)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my `build.gradle`, I define some 3rd party libs, all of which are available in Maven Central.

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.14.2'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.14.2'
}
```

(We also have manually managed jars under `libs` (for Eclipse users), and I used to use those 
for Gradle builds too, with `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`, but I'm trying to move away from that towards simpler, automated dependency management.)

Anyway, for some reason fetching the deps fails:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp-Android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
     Required by:
         :MyApp-Android:unspecified
   > Could not find com.google.guava:guava:15.0.
     Required by:
         :MyApp-Android:unspecified
   > Could not find com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.14.2.
     Required by:
         :MyApp-Android:unspecified
   > Could not find com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.14.2.
     Required by:
         :MyApp-Android:unspecified
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was wondering if I should have

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

...also on the top level of the build file (not just inside `buildscript`), but adding that didn't help.

### Resolution

I was too hasty; that **did** help with "Could not resolve dependencies". After that I got compilation errors, but that was due to in fact having some more dependendies in the code (and in `libs`) than the four entries in `dependendies` above.

So in my case I had to add the top-level `repositories` pointing to Maven Central **plus** some additional dependiencies that we actually had:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'   
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0'
```

---

The (original, broken) full `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.14.2'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.14.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the top-level repository declaration?

Comment: @Peter: If you read the whole question, especially around "Resolution", and the answer + its comments, it should be all clear.

Comment: Got confused because the original, incomplete `build.gradle` comes after `resolution`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed you need to add a

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

at the top level of your `build.gradle` to specify where to search for your dependencies.

Comment: It's hard to believe that this wouldn't help. Try with `--refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: Just tried with one of my projects and it worked as expected after a `gradlew clean build`

Comment: Ah, wait! I get a different errors with that: the *compilation* doesn't work. So I suppose I have to somehow add the fetched jars to classpath... Do you happen to know to do that (see my build.gradle above)?

Comment: My bad: the compilation errors were about *different* dependiencies (e.g. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)) that we had in `libs` directory but I forgot to include in `build.gradle`. I just have to add those. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Jonik I got the same problem. In my case I had accidentally commented out the necessary lines. For people who, like me and you have deps in libs dir, add this to your build.gradle:

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
=>        mavenCentral()     <=

    }
```