# Android Studio gradle refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there are a couple of threads on this but none seem to solve my problem. I just installed `Android Studio` v0.4.6 on my Mac. Every time I create a new project I get the error:

```
 Gradle 'Budget' project refresh failed:
        Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

In more detail I get:

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Budget'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0.
     Required by:
         :Budget:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:22.4.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:22.4.2
      > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.0/asm-analysis-4.0.pom
         > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.0.
     Required by:
         :Budget:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:22.4.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:22.4.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:22.4.2
      > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.pom
         > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. I tried updating `Android Studio` to v0.5, changing the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

and both of those failed. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog" is an XML validation error -- it looks like it's trying to download a POM file from Maven Central to resolve a dependency, and the file it's getting is bad. I'm guessing it's some sort of network or proxy problem, and it's returning an error page when it tries to fetch the URL. I tried including a `compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0'` dependency in a test project, and it works fine for me, so it must be something about your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you should have installed the newest version of Android Studio which is 0.5.5.
   Then update your `gradle plugin` version to the newest one --> 0.9.+

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
   }
   ```
2. You should check you repositories if all modules/libraries have a correct URL, eg.

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   ```
3. Verify your `local.properties` and check if a path to Android SDK is correct.
4. Try to build your project in the Terminal using your local Gradle distribution and Gradle wrapper:
   Local distribution:

   ```
   gradle clean build
   ```

   Wrapper:

   ```
   ./gradlew clean build
   ```

   If you don't have the local distribution, install the newest version using e.g homebrew (for mac users) (`brew install gradle`).
5. Set the path to the local Gradle distribution in the Android Studio (default path for brew and mac is: `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.11/libexec/`).
6. After all these steps close your project and import it again (like you import the project for the very first time).

Comment: My dependencies and repositories both match yours now but the error is still there. My SDK directory is: `sdk.dir=/Users/Ryan/Documents/Android/sdk` which is where the folder for the SDK is, should it be more specific?

Comment: No, it's ok. Did you build your project in terminal? Using your local distribution of gradle and gradle wrapper as well? 
Verify your local gradle version --> `gradle --version`. You should have the newest version which is 1.11.

Comment: When I checked the version it said `gradle: command not found.` Do I need to install gradle separately or should it come with AS?

Comment: If you have a proper gradle wrapper, you don't have to install it. However it could be helpful in a process of finding a solution for your problem. Install homebrew and then install the newest version of gradle. --> `brew install gradle`

Comment: Ok I installed it and I do have version 1.11. Now how would I build my project in the terminal? Right now I'm still getting the error

Comment: Write `gradle clean build` in your project folder - there you should have also `build. gradle` and `settings.gradle` files

Comment: Ok, I did all that, the build was successful but when I open Android Studio it's still giving me that error

Comment: Have you set a path to your Gradle distribution in Android Studio?

Comment: Right now it is set to the default wrapper one, the next thing I was going to try was setting it to the local one but I don't know what the path is or how to find that

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.11/libexec/`
After that close your project and import it again (like you import the project for the very first time)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your gradle to this:

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'

 }
```

Comment: I did that and it still failed, I added a more detailed error on my question

Comment: try using this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933935/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-with-3rd-party-libs-from-maven-central it might give you an idea

Comment: Current version is `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'`